# Не могу понять, почему результат выполнения команд меняется от выполнения к выполнению

Tags: shell, консоль, командная-строка, wget, fish-shell

Выполняю следующую команду в fish shell:

```
wget -nv --spider 'https://dl.google.com/go/go1.10.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz' 2>&1 | grep '200 OK'
```

Результат выполнения разнится от запуска к запуску.

Или выводит:

```
2018-05-27 22:16:21 URL: https://dl.google.com/go/go1.10.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz 200 OK
```

Или выполняется молча.

При этом если не использовать pipe, то wget выполняется всегда одинаково. 
В bash такого эффекта не заметил.